# How to show alert dialogue from another thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've got an app that has a class that's linked to a layout. This layout then runs a process in another thread to avoid freezing the layout. Eventually, the code in the second thread is supposed to show a dialogue on the layout in the first thread. The code is running. I know this because I put a print statement at the end of it, but the dialogue isn't showing up.

So how do I make the dialogue show up once the thread is done? As far as I can tell, I can't just plop it into another thread, so i'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create object of Handler in onCreate()

```
 mHandler=new Handler();
```

then

write following code inside your thread where you want to display dialog or to update any UI views.

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
        //Add all dialog prepaation code
    }
});
```

For more information refer [Background processing in Android](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use runOnUiThread from the thread to access your views and update/edit it.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        btn.setText("#");
                        //show your dialog here
                       //do your work here
                    }
                });
```

and if you are using fragments just add `getActivity()` before `runOnUiThread`